# Iterating an Object using .map to display the inner array values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON **stringified object** as:

```
{
  "lesseeName": "Padyster-7",
  "lesseeRegNo": "12345",
  "lesseeVatNo": "4456",
  "telFaxNo": "1234567891",
  "billingAddress": {
    "addressId": null,
    "addressLine1": "XYz , l1 street",
    "addressLine2": "near xyz bank",
    "postalCode": "60000",
    "countryName": "MY",
    "cityName": "Kuala lumpur",
    "stateProvinceCode": "Kuala lumpur"
  },
  "mlaList": [{
    "mlaNo": 92,
    "lesseeId": 108,
    "executionDate": "27/01/2017",
    "signatoryInfo": "Test",
    "overdueRate": 3.44,
    "nonPaymentDays": 2,
    "consolidationTerm": "Monthly",
    "createdBy": null,
    "createdDtm": null,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedDtm": null,
    "statusIndicator": null,
    "signatoryEmail": "tooot@gmail.com",
    "leaseMlaNo": "OPM1",
    "statusDescription": "APPROVED"
  }, {
    "mlaNo": 93,
    "lesseeId": 108,
    "executionDate": "03/01/2017",
    "signatoryInfo": "tess",
    "overdueRate": 5.77,
    "nonPaymentDays": 2,
    "consolidationTerm": "Bi-Monthly",
    "createdBy": null,
    "createdDtm": null,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedDtm": null,
    "statusIndicator": null,
    "signatoryEmail": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "leaseMlaNo": "OPM2",
    "statusDescription": "APPROVED"
  }]
}
```

I am working in Reactjs and I want my object to be iterated such that the inner array **mlaList** of objects gets iterated to display value one after other.
whenever I try using the .map function to the parent object I get an error saying ".map is not a function" below is the iteration I attempt which fails:

```
{data.map((data, index) => {data.leaseMlaNo} &nbsp; {data.signatoryEmail})}
```

I have referred to the SO questions quite similar to this one, but they just talk about iterating the objects using Object.keys

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and what should be the correct way to achieve this

Comment: `data.mlaList.map`

Comment: `data` is an object isn't it? Not an array?

Comment: `.map` belongs to Arrays and not Objects

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes

Comment: @OMTheEternity Well, there's your problem. You can't iterate objects like that, since they don't have a map method.

Comment: @Carcigenicate then what should be the right way as I have tried the solutions provided below but it still breaks as I have mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a method of the Array class, and not of the Object class. However, the `mlaList` property is an array, and you can iterate it. You should use `data.mlaList.map()`:

```js
// if the data is stringified - const data = JSON.parse({ the object });
const data = {"lesseeName":"Padyster-7","lesseeRegNo":"12345","lesseeVatNo":"4456","telFaxNo":"1234567891","billingAddress":{"addressId":null,"addressLine1":"XYz , l1 street","addressLine2":"near xyz bank","postalCode":"60000","countryName":"MY","cityName":"Kuala lumpur","stateProvinceCode":"Kuala lumpur"},"mlaList":[{"mlaNo":92,"lesseeId":108,"executionDate":"27/01/2017","signatoryInfo":"Test","overdueRate":3.44,"nonPaymentDays":2,"consolidationTerm":"Monthly","createdBy":null,"createdDtm":null,"updatedBy":null,"updatedDtm":null,"statusIndicator":null,"signatoryEmail":"tooot@gmail.com","leaseMlaNo":"OPM1","statusDescription":"APPROVED"},{"mlaNo":93,"lesseeId":108,"executionDate":"03/01/2017","signatoryInfo":"tess","overdueRate":5.77,"nonPaymentDays":2,"consolidationTerm":"Bi-Monthly","createdBy":null,"createdDtm":null,"updatedBy":null,"updatedDtm":null,"statusIndicator":null,"signatoryEmail":"xyz@gmail.com","leaseMlaNo":"OPM2","statusDescription":"APPROVED"}]};

const result = data.mlaList.map((o, index) => o.signatoryEmail); // in react <div key={index}>{o.signatoryEmail}</div> for example

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Have Updated by Question, the object given is a JSONstringified one, so it makes mlaList as array of object as well

Comment: The object is a string that needs to be parsed?

Comment: Anyway, the structure is the same, and you can access an object's properties using the . notation - `o.signatoryEmail`.

Comment: The code was working, I was doing a console.log on the object this.props.data.mlaList under render() method and then at the same time iterating the object under return(...map()...).. and hence it was breaking, though i dont understand whats the reason behind it, can you please help?

Comment: It seems like the problem is in render. Open another question with less data - `{  "mlaList": [{ just the properties you want to render}] }`, and the component you are trying to render.

Comment: I have created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968938/console-log-to-props-breaks-when-used-with-its-iteration-using-map-in-render-me) for the mentioned issue

Answer (score 2):

[array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array function, not for objects so you would want to call it on your mlalist key:

```js
const data = {"lesseeName":"Padyster-7","lesseeRegNo":"12345","lesseeVatNo":"4456","telFaxNo":"1234567891","billingAddress":{"addressId":null,"addressLine1":"XYz , l1 street","addressLine2":"near xyz bank","postalCode":"60000","countryName":"MY","cityName":"Kuala lumpur","stateProvinceCode":"Kuala lumpur"},"mlaList":[{"mlaNo":92,"lesseeId":108,"executionDate":"27/01/2017","signatoryInfo":"Test","overdueRate":3.44,"nonPaymentDays":2,"consolidationTerm":"Monthly","createdBy":null,"createdDtm":null,"updatedBy":null,"updatedDtm":null,"statusIndicator":null,"signatoryEmail":"tooot@gmail.com","leaseMlaNo":"OPM1","statusDescription":"APPROVED"},{"mlaNo":93,"lesseeId":108,"executionDate":"03/01/2017","signatoryInfo":"tess","overdueRate":5.77,"nonPaymentDays":2,"consolidationTerm":"Bi-Monthly","createdBy":null,"createdDtm":null,"updatedBy":null,"updatedDtm":null,"statusIndicator":null,"signatoryEmail":"xyz@gmail.com","leaseMlaNo":"OPM2","statusDescription":"APPROVED"}]};
const list = data.mlaList.map(val => `${val.leaseMlaNo} ${val.signatoryEmail}`);
console.log(list)
```