# console.log to props breaks when used with its iteration using .map in render method

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I have an object I received from a parent component as props. In render method, when printed with console.log prints me the complete object but it prints empty when the same object is being iterated using.map for html tags to print the values.

Cannot understand why this behavior, this is an extension from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955707/iterating-an-object-using-map-to-display-the-inner-array-values) the complete object is available in that question, below is the part of object which is being iterated:

```
"mlaList": [{
    "mlaNo": 92,
    "lesseeId": 108,
    "executionDate": "27/01/2017",
    "signatoryInfo": "Test",
    "overdueRate": 3.44,
    "nonPaymentDays": 2,
    "consolidationTerm": "Monthly",
    "createdBy": null,
    "createdDtm": null,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedDtm": null,
    "statusIndicator": null,
    "signatoryEmail": "tooot@gmail.com",
    "leaseMlaNo": "OPM1",
    "statusDescription": "APPROVED"
  }, {
    "mlaNo": 93,
    "lesseeId": 108,
    "executionDate": "03/01/2017",
    "signatoryInfo": "tess",
    "overdueRate": 5.77,
    "nonPaymentDays": 2,
    "consolidationTerm": "Bi-Monthly",
    "createdBy": null,
    "createdDtm": null,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedDtm": null,
    "statusIndicator": null,
    "signatoryEmail": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "leaseMlaNo": "OPM2",
    "statusDescription": "APPROVED"
  }]
```

below is the component in which render method is also available with the mentioned code:

```
class AddLesseeInfoMLA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handlePrev = this.handlePrev.bind(this)
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this)
  }

  handlePrev() {
    this.props.changeNavFunction(this.props.prevStep)
  }

  handleNext() {
    this.props.changeNavFunction(this.props.nextStep)
  }

  render() {
          console.log("Result::"+this.props.data)
    return (
      <div id="add-facility-info-profile-form-wrapper">
        <Validation.components.Form id="add-facility-terms-info-form" ref="form" className="melody-common-form">
          <div id="add-facility-terms-info-form">
            {this.props.data.mlaList.map((data, index) =>
              <div className="add-facility-terms-info-form-wrapper2" key={index}>
                <div className="inputContainer melody-common-form-label">
                  <label className={index === 0 ? '' : 'melody-common-display-none'}>Lease MLA Number</label>
                  <Validation.components.Input value={data.leaseMlaNo} id="leaseMlaNo" className="short melody-common-input-disabled" type="text" name="leaseMlaNo" ref="leaseMlaNo" disabled="true" />
                </div>
                <div className="inputContainer melody-common-form-label">
                  <label className={index === 0 ? '' : 'melody-common-display-none'}>Status</label>
                  <Validation.components.Input value={data.statusDescription} id="statusDescription" className="short melody-common-input-disabled" type="text" name="statusDescription" ref="statusDescription" disabled="true" />
                </div>
                <div className="inputContainer melody-common-form-label">
                  <label className={index === 0 ? '' : 'melody-common-display-none'}>Consolidation Term</label>
                  <Validation.components.Input value={data.consolidationTerm} id="consolidationTerm" className="short melody-common-input-disabled" type="text" name="consolidationTerm" ref="consolidationTerm" disabled="true" />
                </div>
                <div className="inputContainer melody-common-form-label">
                  <label className={index === 0 ? '' : 'melody-common-display-none'}>Overdue Rate (%)</label>
                  <Validation.components.Input value={dataFormatter.toPercentFormat(data.overdueRate)} id="overdueRate" className="short melody-common-input-disabled" type="text" name="overdueRate" ref="overdueRate"  disabled="true" />
                </div>
                <div className="inputContainer melody-common-form-label">
                  <label className={index === 0 ? '' : 'melody-common-display-none'}>Non Payment Days</label>
                  <Validation.components.Input value={data.nonPaymentDays} id="nonPaymentDays" className="short melody-common-input-disabled" type="text" name="nonPaymentDays" ref="nonPaymentDays" disabled="true" />
                </div> 
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </Validation.components.Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default AddLesseeInfoMLA
```

Comment: Can you update the question to make it clear when does it return `undefined` exactly?

Comment: @NaisheelVerdhan it doesnt yield undefined, it displays blank with given code, but if I Comment the iterating code, i can see the console.log printing my object

Comment: I would suggest you removing most of the child `div`s from inside that `map` function and try to debug it from there. I've noticed with a less strict setup react methods rendering jsx fails without errors.

Comment: @ArchNoob Agree that is the good way to debug. That would also be the good way to ask questions on SO, simplifying things up a bit making the question easier to understand.

Comment: I tried your code in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/llp8p9yqoq). Removed all validation components with form and inputs and it works just fine. PRoblem might be caused by those components. The line by line debugging is a good suggestion.